# Laravel - Set global variable dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, global-variables

I need to set a variable globally but it should be dynamic, means I can (on a certain dashboard page/view) set this variable.

I figured out, that I can set global variables via an ServiceProvider for certain or all views, but how can I set it?  Is it better to put it into a session?

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using view composer for specific view
        view()->composer('*',function($view) {
            $view->with('var_id', ?????????); 
        });
    }
}
```

There should be a link which says (in  example) localhost/setVar1/{id} (setVar1 is an examplename). It should be valid until a user logs out (not the problem here).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you wanting to set a value that will only live for the duration of the current request?  I've used the config system for that in the past..  `config('my_var', $value)` or something like that.

Comment: kind of. A value that the logged in user can set but is valid globally, all views and can be set via view or request.

Comment: You can share a variable with all your views with `View::share('key', 'value')` inside the `boot()` method of the `AppServiceProvider` class. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: this might work but how can I set this variable within my view?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `View::share` in a middleware. So you define in the `routes/web.php` the routes will use the middleware.

Eg.: My `'/user/'` needs to variable 'user', and all routes inside the `'/user/'` need the same variable, so I do this:

In the Middleware file I define `View::share('user', $user)`, and in `routes/web.php` I define:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'MyMiddlewareName'], function() {
 // All the routes
});
```

or put in all the routes need that middleware, just put the `->middleware('MyMiddlewareName');` in the Route, like this

```
Route::get('user', function () {
    //
})->middleware('MyMiddlewareName');
```

Don't forget to set the Middleware in Kernel.php, like this:

```
'MyMiddlewareName' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddlewareName::class
```

And in the Middleware you can verify if the user is in the URL you need.

Comment: that looks great but how can I set this variable to be persistent for the logged in user until he logs out? Middleware is definitely a way to use a variable.

Comment: You can use a `if` in middleware. 
`if(auth()->check() == true) {
// the code to get user details and pass to view
}`

Comment: No. the user needs to set this variable from a view / page like www.localhost.com/setVar/123 - Is there something like View::register or ::set to actually SET a variable?

Comment: Maybe you need to use Session to store this, [in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#storing-data) there are more explain about to do this. So you can store the variable in session and get them with middleware.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i do currently, where i use observer and cache.. i don't know it is the best way or not, it just a suggestion

`Configuration` is my sample model where i load all config when there is an update or new data is created, which i listen with observer

ConfigObserver work as listener to any configuration changes and update the cache

```
class ConfigObserver
{

    public function created(Configuration $setting)
    {
        $this->updateConfig();
    }

    public function deleted(Configuration $setting)
    {
        //
    }

    public function updated(Configuration $setting)
    {
        $this->updateConfig();
    }

    private function updateConfig()
    {
        //store in cache
        Cache::forever('configuration', Configuration::pluck('value', 'key')->toArray());
    }
}
```

in AppServiceProvider in boot method, set the observer to the Configuration Model

```
Configuration::observe(new ConfigObserver());
```

then, user `view()` method either in `AppServiceProvider` or `Middleware`

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
      //check if cache is not available, just query it back and store, then pass to view
      $config = Cache::get('configuration', function () {
          return Cache::forever('configuration', Configuration::pluck('value', 'key')->toArray());
      });
      $view->with('config', $config);
});
```